# Imagick resized image content direct upload to ECS Server - PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using the following code to upload image content to the ECS server

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
        'Key'    => $Destination_folder,
        'Body'   => $image_content 
        ));
```

Earlier I was storying the image to a temporary location and then convering it into 3 images of different size (using Imagick) and then uploading those images individually.

Now I am able to upload the image directly using the image content and I also figured out how to resize the image using the image content. Following is the code for that using Imagick

```
$imagick->readImageBlob($imageBlob);
$res = $imagick->scaleImage(10, 10, true);
$writeSuccess = $imagick->writeImage("abc-m.jpeg");
```

But now I want to upload the image directly to the ECS server after resizing but without using temporary loaction.

How can I uplaod the resized image from Imagick to ECS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use getImageBlob()
`$image_content = $imagick->getImageBlob();`
Now upload this image content to the server.